# this & bind returning Undefined

Tags: javascript

Please explain to me why this isn't working when learning about `this` & the `bind` idea:

```js
var numbers = {
  x: 'hi',
  y: 'dawd',
  z: 'ohgroe',
};

function calc() {
  calc.bind(numbers);
  return this.x + this.y + this.z;
}

calc();
```

Why is this not returning this simple calculation?

Comment: You do realize `calc.bind(numbers)` returns a new function with bound arguments? It does not change `calc` in place. The best solution would be not to bind inside the function, that makes no sense. Use `calc.call(numbers)`.

Comment: You catched my attention with the rhyme ;)

Comment: Have a look at [YDJS - this & object prototypes](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20&%20object%20prototypes/README.md#you-dont-know-js-this--object-prototypes) if you want to learn about `this`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bind` returns a function. It doesn't bind the object to the current function. You need to use something like `calc.bind(numbers)()` or `calc.call(numbers)`.

These calls need to be done outside the function. Here is an example:

```js
var numbers = {
  x: 'hi',
  y: 'dawd',
  z: 'ohgroe',
};

function calc() {
  return this.x + this.y + this.z;
}

var result =  calc.bind(numbers)();
// OR
// var result = calc.call(numbers);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Be careful. You're making a recursive call with no escape clause.

Comment: @llama You're right I should have been more specific and say that this needs to be done outside the function.

Answer (score 1):

`this` will be set to the `numbers` object only in the *invocation* of the function *returned* from `.bind()`. It doesn't change the local `this` value.

I'm not sure what you were ultimately after when using `.bind()`, so I don't know what to suggest for a solution. Maybe describe the original problem you were trying to solve.

Comment: The idea came from Helloreact.io .. It was in the scope of a tutorial/lesson about `this` and `bind`. The thought of it is that `this` cannot be used in a function unless the var has been specified within.

Comment: Oh, yeah that's actually done on the invocation side of things. You can use `var newCalc = calc.bind(numbers)` to create a new function that has its `this` value bound to the `numbers` object. So when you invoke that new function, the value of `this` will (almost) always be `numbers`.

Comment: @helle oh, that cant go well :/ try to learn proper js first, then continue with react. Starting with react is like driving a car before youre able to walk ;)

Comment: @jonas-w It's just the name of the website. The course is for javascript

Comment: @helle no, why would they name it *react* than?? And the first page says *This course assumes a light knowledge of HTML, CSS and JavaScript. However, if you have been using any of those technologies for at least a couple months you will be in good shape for this course*

Comment: @Jonasw The course title is `JavaScript Basics'. Not trying to argue, just making sure that I am in the right category and that you know I am not confusing things. I'm sure the library and Vanilla JS share the basics

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to set `this` within the function call itself you can define expected parameters to the function

```js
var numbers = {
  x: 'hi',
  y: 'dawd',
  z: 'ohgroe',
};

function calc({x = "", y = "", z = ""} = {}) {
  return x + y + z;
}

console.log(calc(numbers));
```

Comment: Wohoo! Parameter object destructuring for newbies ;)

Comment: @Jonasw Why not? Probably equal curve to setting `this`

Answer (score 0):

Some ways it would work:

```
function calc() {
  return this.x + this.y + this.z;
}

console.log(calc.call(numbers));
 //equals calc.bind(numbers)()
```

Or using with

```
function calc(){
  with(numbers){
    return x + y + z;
  }
}

console.log(calc());
```

Or passing numbers:

```
function calc(nums){
  return nums.x + nums.y + nums.z;
}

 console.log( calc(numbers));
```

Then you directly could do that for *n* values:

```
fuction calc(nums){
  return Object.values(nums).reduce((a,b) => a + b );
}

console.log(calc( {
 a:1,b:4,c:5
}));
```

> I feel like giving up on JS

No! Dont do this! JS is one of the coolest languages currently available, and even if its hard to learn it will be worth it i promise ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
function calc() {
  calc.bind(numbers);
  return this.x + this.y + this.z;
}
```

This creates a new 'this' scope and binds calc to numbers (this does not execute calc, but rather binds numbers to its function call, this does not add it to the this state of the call either). Your calls to this are now doing nothing. Now if you do this

```
function calc() {
  Object.assign(this, numbers);
  return this.x + this.y + this.z;
}
```

X Y and Z are bound to the scope. I have no idea why you would ever do this though, why don't you just do this?

```
function calc(numbers) {
  return numbers.x + numbers.y + numbers.z;
}
```

Comment: Why not `Object.assign( this, numbers );` ? ;)

Comment: I suppose cleaner syntax is always nicer.

Comment: I figured there'd be numerous solutions. In this case, the point was to learn the concept as taught by helloreact. Great explanation, and you just taught me about the `Object.assign()` method, too. Thank you mucho

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it is important to understand bind, call, apply.  All let you control what object 'this' points to, but they do it differently.

bind() returns a copy of the function.

call() actually executes the function instead of just creating a copy and can also be passed parameters..

apply() is the same as call() but takes an array when passing in parameters.

With this in mind you can do the following:

```
var numbers = {
  x: 'hi',
  y: 'dawd',
  z: 'ohgroe',
};

function calc() {
  return this.x + this.y + this.z;
}

var boundedCalc = calc.bind(numbers);
boundedCalc();
```

or

```
calc.call(numbers);
```

or

```
calc.apply(numbers)
```